# Apparent contradiction Between Theorem About Hausdorff Topologies and Discrete Sets

Tags: general-topology

I am currently studying John M. Lee's "Topological Manifolds", where in chapter 2 it states the following:

> Suppose $X$ is a Hausdorff space and $A\subseteq X$. If $p\in X$ is a limit
>   point of $A$, then every neighborhood of $p$ contains infinitely many points of $A.$

However, just previous to this, the book also stated that discrete sets have a Hausdorff space (the discrete topology). It appears to me that these two theorems are in contradiction, so what am I missing?

Comment: Discrete spaces have no limit points. (A subspace $D$ that is discrete may have limit points in the surrounding space $X$, if it is not closed, but none of the limit points lies in $D$.)

Comment: @DanielFischer You should make that an answer. (If you don't, I will make it a CW answer. :) )

Comment: It would be easier to give a useful answer if you gave some hint of why you think these results contradict each other.

Comment: Titles claiming there is a "Contradiction" when there is none are inappropriate.

Comment: I did not mean to imply that I have found a contradiction, only that that the material appeared to be contradictory. I will take more care with titles in the future.

Comment: By the way, it is true also for $T_1$-spaces, not just for $T_2$-spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably are missing a detail in the definition of a limit point,

Let $S \subset X$, where $X$ is a topological space. A point $x \in X$ is a *limit point* of $S$, if for each neighbourhood $V$ of $x$, $(V \setminus\{x\}) \cap S \neq \varnothing$.

Equivalently, $x$ is a limit point of $S$ if and only if $x \in \overline{S\setminus\{x\}}$.

From that follows that in a discrete space, no set has a limit point, since each point $x$ has a neighbourhood $V$ such that $V\setminus\{x\} = \varnothing$.

A subspace $D \subset X$ that is discrete in the subspace topology may have limit points in $X$, though (example: $\{ \frac1n : n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ has $0$ as a limit point, but is discrete in the subspace topology). But none of the limit points lies in $D$.